# Kotlin realm is not empty after delete and close

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

I new to realm database, i implemented it like these :

```
realmConfing = RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                    .name("realmName")
                    .schemaVersion(REALM_SCHEMA_VERSION)
                    .migration(MyMigration())
                    .modules(Realm.getDefaultModule(), UserModule())
                    .allowWritesOnUiThread(true)
                    .allowQueriesOnUiThread(true)
                    .build()
```

For the configuration, then this to add my user :

```
internal fun addRealmUser(accessToken: String, organisation: String, login: String) {
            var realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfing)
            println(realm!!.isEmpty)
            if (realm!!.isEmpty) {
                realm!!.executeTransactionAsync { realm ->
                    val user: RealmUser = realm.createObject(RealmUser::class.java)
                    user.setLogin(login)
                    user.setOrganization(organisation)
                    user.setAccessToken(accessToken)
                   
               }
 }
```

I use this to log in and signin my user and to save some data. And when i log ou i do this :

```
var realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfing)
            realm?.executeTransaction { r: Realm ->
                realm.deleteAll()
            }

            realm?.close()
```

So after i logout my data are clear and my realm doesn't have any data anymore, how ever when i try so sign in again, realm!!.isEmpty = false so it doesn't enter in my method to add the user. am I missing something ? or i'an doing something wrong when i clear data ? i don't understand why i don't have any data in my realm anymore but it's telling me that it's not empty?

**EDIT**

As someone suggested i used mongodb realm studio to make sure that my datas are cleared. here is what i got after login, data are correctly saved and i can use them : [image: User data]

And this is what i got after logout, my data are cleared and i don't have a user anymore. [image]

But when i do realm.isEmpty i still get false. does anyone know where does it come from ? also realm.isEmpty is working because the first time i log in it give me true. but after the logout and clearing data, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Did you try opening your Realm with MongoDB Realm Studio to see if there are any objects?

Comment: I tried realm studio to check and my data are cleared after logout.

Comment: I created a new Realm app. In the app I have a button that populates Realm with some data and another button that deletes all data using `realm.deleteAll` and then a third button that tests to see if data is present using `if realm.isEmpty {` and outputs *empty* to the console if true and *not empty* to the console as false. Upon running the app, when data is in realm, that button prints 'not empty' and then after pressing the button to deleteAll, it then prints 'empty'. So it's working as intended. I would guess you have something else going on or maybe you're examining the wrong realm file.